# org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.MongoDBTokenStore

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-security

Has anyone else encountered the need for a MongoDB implementation of the TokenStore?  Any words of advice from anyone that has encountered this?

My team's current project is a polyglot, we're moving more towards MongoDB.  The JDBCTokenStore (org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore) would be ideal out-of-the-box solution if we were to stay in an RDBMS but we're going schema-less for security.  I'm working on something quick and dirty, but would like to contribute something more solid to the community.  Just wondering if anyone else is interested.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this implementation of a mongodb token store:

https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/porterhead/oauth2/mongodb/OAuth2RepositoryTokenStore.java

The accompanying blog post might be helpful too:

http://porterhead.blogspot.com/2014/05/securing-rest-services-with-spring.html